# How to resolve the error while importing smtplib using Python 3.6.9?

Tags: python, pycharm, python-3.6

I wanted to send a mail with attachment, so first I was trying to send mail using python 3.6 and using pycharm IDE. Every time while running the file I get the following exception.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/UDHAV.MOHATA/script/test.py", line 11, in <module>
    import smtplib
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 47, in <module>
    import email.utils
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/utils.py", line 28, in <module>
    import random
  File "/home/UDHAV.MAHATA/script/random.py", line 1, in <module>
    import urllib3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3'
```

**Sample code:**

```
import smtplib
import ssl

subject = "An email with attachment from Python"
body = "This is an email with attachment sent from Python"
sender_email = "***********"
receiver_email = "***************"
password = "********"

message = """\
Subject: Hi there

This message is sent from Python."""

context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL_PORT("smtp.gmail.com", 465, context=context) as server:
    server.login(sender_email, password)
    server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)
```

**Exact python version:** 3.6.9

My motive is to send a mail with an attachment. If anyone knows the fix for this import exception or another way. Please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You named your file `random.py`, which causes `import random` in `/usr/lib/python3.6/email/utils.py` to import your own script instead of the standard lib `random` module. In turn, your own `random.py` file imports `urllib3` which apparently is not installed on your interpreter.

Never name your script/module with the same name of a standard lib built-in/module.

To fix this error you will need to:

- Change the name of **your** `random.py`.
- Install the `urllib3` so your script can import it (if you really need it)

Comment: Its working now. I just realised I had another file named random.py, thats why it was failing. Thanks!!